# probability that taxies T1 & T2 are used to their full capacity

Tags: probability, permutations

Here is the question

> T1, T2 & T3 are three different taxies, each having 3 duly numbered seats for the passenger.
> Seven passenger are to accommodated in these taxies. If probability that taxies T1 & T2 are used
> to their full capacity is $\frac{m}{n}$
> $m, n\in N$, then the least value of $n-4m$ is

My approach:

Clearly $T_1,T_2,T_3$ contain $3,3,1$ passengers respectively and the three passengers in each taxi can be arranged amongst themselves so number of favourable cases is $$n(F)=\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1}3!3!1!$$ and total number of cases is $$n(T)=\binom{9}{7}7!$$ hence $$P=\frac{n(F)}{n(T)}=1/36$$ and $n-4m=32$

But the answer given is $8$ where have I gone wrong??

Comment: This is not clear to me how we have decided to arrange the passengers among the taxis.  What random process is used to determine who ends in which taxi?  Note that arrangements counted by stars-and-bars are in most real world circumstances *not* equally likely to occur.

Comment: For instance... is it the case that the first passenger comes up and picks a taxi uniformly at random from those which are not yet at full capacity, then the second passenger comes up and picks a taxi uniformly at random from those which are not yet at full capacity, rinse and repeat, noting that once a taxi has reached full capacity it may no longer be selected?

Comment: @JMoravitz when they said the seats are duly numbered I guess they mean we have to count the cases when the passengers can be arranged in the seats

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Are you saying then that the random process involved is that there is a ticket booth with nine tickets, each labeled a number from $1$ to $9$, each number appearing exactly once each and then each person comes up, takes a ticket uniformly at random from those that are left, and sits in the corresponding seat (where seats 1-3 are in the first taxi, 4-6 are in the second taxi, etc...)?  That is a completely different distribution than the one described in my second comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes that is what I assumed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is far more convenient for your problem in the interpretation of the distribution chosen to imagine that rather than there being seven passengers... that there are instead seven *living* passengers *and two ghosts*.  The ghosts will otherwise act the same as the passengers and will take tickets and sit in their respective seats.

The arrangement of living passengers being 3-3-1 (*the first two taxis at capacity for living passengers*) corresponds exactly then to the scenario of both ghosts sitting in the third taxi.  That occurs with probability $\dfrac{3}{9}\times\dfrac{2}{8}=\dfrac{1}{12}$

Your answer was close to correct for your given interpretation, however it made one crucial mistake.  That is, when you calculated your numerator, $\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1}3!3!\color{red}{1!}$ this $1!$ should have corresponded to the number of ways that the passenger in the third taxi could have arranged themself... but we are not caring about how they arrange with respect to other non-existent passengers.  We care here about *which seat they are sitting in* and there were three seats available.  This should have been a $3$, not a $1$.

In doing so, your answer will after more tedious arithmetic than I performed above also result in $\dfrac{1}{12}$, resulting in your final calculation of $n-4m = 12-4=8$ as expected.

Comment: Liked the ghosts ! (+1)